# Спорю с сайтом: к-т или с-ш, - что образует слог (см.)?

Tags: слоги

[Слоговыми могут быть](http://refwin.ru/1620109097.html)

> не только сонорные согласные, но и шумные, даже глухие. Так русские подзывают кошку кс-кс-кс. В этом междометии три слога, хотя все звуки глухие. Слоговым здесь является звук [с]. Глухой щелевой согласный выступает слоговым и в возгласе отпугивания птиц кш! И в призыве к молчанию тс!

Мне кажется, что слоги "кыс", "кыш" и "тыс" заслуга не последнего звука, а первого, - рассудите нас, люди!

Новые примеры; прошу обратить внимание на слова в предпоследней строке: съпʌг'и́, тъпʌры́... - *с* и *т* слогообразующие!

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

***Шумный согласный, стоящий в начале консонантного сочетания!***

Но я всё равно не уверена, что правильно всё поняла, вопрос остаётся актуальным.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Галина, я чаще всего на Вашей стороне, но не в данном случае. По ссылке shampar хорошая статья:

Слоговые согласные отличаются от неслоговых большей напряженностью: щелевые — долготой, звонкие взрывные — долгой смычкой, глухие взрывные — придыхательностью, дрожащие — многоударностью, раскатистостью. Таким образом, вершину слога может образовывать не только самый сонорный звук в слоге, но и самый напряженный.

Произнесём кс-кс-кс. Напряжённый здесь никак не К: К-К-К-С.  Напряжённый (поётся) как раз С: К-С-С-С и К-Ш-Ш-Ш , а вовсе не К-К-К-Ш

Comment: Вот теперь понял-не-дурак! Мне бы все объяснения на таком уровне, как в Вашем последнем абзаце!

Answer (score 1):

Мне кажется, что пишут правильно, то есть слог образуют С и Ш. Если Вы замените в *кс-кс-кс* второй согласный (С) на, например, Н или Д, слоги звучать не будут, а если замените К на эти же или любой другой, — тогда будут.

И, как у Сержа и у этого словаря, у меня нету в *кс-кс-кс* и *тс* звука Ы, только *кыш* я ещё могу так сказать.

Comment: Ужасно интересно!!! Вдруг ещё кто придёт со штампом "уплочено"? В кыс и тыс у меня Ы не открытое, а очень сильно редуцированное. Иначе вообще эти звукоподражания и междометия не должны были попасть в примеры слоговых согласных.

Comment: Галина, я уже вам ответил в том вопросе. См.последний комментарий.

Answer (score 1):

http://refwin.ru/1620109097.html даёт внятное объяснение относительно **кс** и др., где нет гласной: слоговая там — щелевая и долгая ***С***. В равно популярном варианте с гласными (***кис*** или ***кыс***), который сайт мог бы упомянуть, но не стал, уже они должны быть названы слоговыми.